# How to behave with 10 months old baby around staircases?

Tags: toddler, safety

I understand staircases are very dangerous for babies.

We have only one staircase at our home. The staircase is 20 cm high.

Our baby is very curious and wants to go down that one staircase (20 cm high) and into the other room to explore it.

I'd like to safely introduce the staircase to my baby. How should I do this?
How should I approach teaching a 10 months old baby about the staircase?

Comment: [Related](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11921/420)

Comment: Please read the duplicate question and answers; if they do not answer your question, or you feel your question is asking about a different aspect/matter, please edit your question and flag for reopening. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The key word here: **Backwards**

As soon as your baby starts to move independently, teach him or her how to manage obstacles. And the safest way is to slide down backwards. Start as soon as they crawl and pick one *keyword* - like "backwards" - that you use whenever he gets to crawl or slide down either from a mattress, down a stair or later down the sofa. Help him to turn his rear towards "the abbyss" and go down feet first. With some patience and constant reminders, it will become automatic.

With only one step or "mini-staircase" in your house, this is the comparatively safe and in any case more versatile tactic compared to simply blocking access.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a [baby gate](http://parent.guide/how-to-baby-proof-your-stairs/) (the link is just an example, you can definitely Google from more options).

Using a baby gate allows you to block the staircase from either side, preventing the bay from accidentally using it. The height might not sound as much, by babies are rather fragile. You can transport the baby from on room to the other by carrying him / her. The room can now be safely explored!

I would wait with introducing the staircase as something to explore until he / she can walk stably (without keeling over of doing a buttdrop) and with confidence (young walkers tend to "stamp" the ground).

Comment: Although make sure to remove the babygate as soon as the child can climb over it, because at that point they become more dangerous than no gate.